# Hankel transformation

Tags: linear-transformations, integral-transforms

How to solve the Hankel transform of $x^2e^{-ax}$ with kernel $x(J_2(px))$ where $J_n(x)$ denotes bessel function of order $n$ of first kind?

Comment: pleas learn how to use $Tex$. We fixed the question this time for u

Comment: Sorry.. There is a correction.. Its x^(-2)